# Removing grey margin from exported map of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, export

[image]

In above image there is a gray color margin.

Is there any way I can change the color of it in to white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are exporting to JPEG or PNG for example there is an option to change the background to white, see below:

[image]